# Attempted to create a for loop for my aliens to zig-zag across the grid after the eventlistener button is clicked- not working

Tags: javascript

> is there something wrong with the syntax and or logic? the aliens just aren't moving on the grid i have built. when the game loads, the aliens are triggered by the eventlistener of the start button. the aim is tohave the aliens move one box to the left, then one row down, then once box to the right, and one row down again. this is the loop i wanted to create with these movements.

```
function aliensMove() {
      for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
     if cell.addEventListener('click', ('.start') => {     
     (alien > ((gridSize) - width - 1)) {
      return
       }
    cells[alien].classList.remove('alien')
    alien = alien + width
    cells[alien].classList.add('alien')

if (alien > ((gridSize) - width - 1)) {
     return
    }
 cells[alien].classList.remove('alien')
 alien = alien + width
cells[alien].classList.add('alien')

if (alien === 0) {
     return
  }

cells[alien].classList.remove('alien')
 alien = alien - 1
   cells[alien].classList.add('alien')
  break

if (alien > ((gridSize) - width - 1)) {
     return
   }
   cells[alien].classList.remove('alien')
  player = player + width
    cells[alien].classList.add('alien')
   }
```

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)` will only iterate once, which doesn't make it very useful. Also, `if cell.addEventListener` is not valid syntax (`if` needs parentheses around the condition) and the return value of `addEventListener` is probably not what you want as your condition. Also, you did not show us where the `alien` variable is defined. Is it defined somewhere? And just a tip: you should use a code formatter like Prettier or ESLint, because with this indentation, missing curly braces and semicolons, it's hard to read

Answer (score 1):

Your question looked like a fun project, so I gave it a try. I did not really understand your code, so this might not really answer your question, but it might give you some ideas. Try it by clicking on the blue button under the code:

```js
var $grid = document.getElementById('grid'),
    width = 40,
    height = 10,
    $rows = makeGrid($grid, width, height);

function makeGrid($container, width, height) {
  var $rows = [];
  for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    var $row = document.createElement('div');
    $row.className = 'row';
    $rows.push([]);
    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      var $cell = document.createElement('div');
      $cell.className = 'cell';
      $row.appendChild($cell);
      $rows[y].push($cell);
    }
    $container.appendChild($row);
  }
  return $rows;
}

function Alien($rows, x, y) {
  this.$rows = $rows;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  // Create an array of moves you will loop through
  this.moves = ['left', 'down', 'right', 'down'];
  this.toggleAlienClass(true);
}

Alien.prototype.move = function() {
  this.toggleAlienClass(false);
  switch (this.moves[0]) {
    case 'left':
      this.x -= 1;
      break;
    case 'right':
      this.x += 1;
      break;
    case 'up':
      this.y -= 1;
      break;
    case 'down':
      this.y += 1;
      break;
  }
  this.toggleAlienClass(true);
  // Remove the first move and push it to the end
  this.moves.push(this.moves.shift());
}

Alien.prototype.toggleAlienClass = function(show) {
  if (this.$rows.length > this.y && this.$rows[this.y].length > this.x) {
    this.$rows[this.y][this.x].classList[show ? 'add' : 'remove']('alien');
  }
}

var aliens = [
  new Alien($rows, 10, 2),
  new Alien($rows, 20, 2),
  new Alien($rows, 30, 2)
];

setInterval(function() {
  aliens.forEach(function(alien) {
    alien.move();
  });
}, 500);
```

```css
#grid {
  background: #222;
  width: 40em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.cell {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  float: left;
}

.cell.alien {
  background: center / contain no-repeat url('https://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/render_9.gif');
}
```

```html
<div id="grid"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this is really helpful and i understand the logic too, it's written out very clearly. I really need to continue practising. Once I get the aliens moving, i need to figure out the lasers!

Comment: Glad it helped! Note that I did not go all the way in using prototypes (like I did for `Alien`), but if you make your entire game like this (including the grid), it will be easier to maintain, and you can create cool helpers, like  `myAlien.move()`, `myAlien.explode()`... You might already know, but this is referred to as [Object Oriented Programming (OOP)](https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2016/04/30/oops-in-js/).